# Can Notepad++ put its block comment characters on new lines?

Tags: notepad++

I already know how to customize the comment characters of NP++ using the lang.xml file.  However, I would like the block comment to automatically put the characters on new lines before and after the selection.

Instead of this:

```
/* This is some multiline text. I'm
just using it as an example. */
```

I would like it to do this:

```
/*
This is some multiline text. I'm
just using it as an example.
*/
```